# RapidMiner Market Place Error

Tags: weka, rapidminer

I tried to add weka extension to RapidMinor. For that I clicked "marketPlace" under extensions in RapidMinor. It gives following error.

[image]

[image]

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Set proxy under preferences under settings in RapidMinor. (Write the ip address and port number connected to each of HTTP,HTTPS and FTP of your computer). For my computer I set it like below.

[image]